# failed to open zip file gradle dependency cache may be corrupt

Tags: android, android-studio

When I updated android studio i got this error. Creating a new project has no issue. I cant build my existing project.

[image: Showing error]

I ve working internet and this error not fixing when i click re-download.
How can i resolve this issue? I ve tried many method found on internet but no luck.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.5'
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.9.8'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete `wrapper` folder in the `gradle` from the project directory.

Answer (score 2):

using gradle-3.3 for example

First: delete the `gradle.zip` in `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-3.3-all.zip`.

Second: delete `wrapper` folder in the `gradle` from the project directory.

Final: resync gradle file in project.